# Plot path from one location to other location on iphone MapView

Tags: iphone, android-mapview

I want to draw path from one location to other location. How to plot the path between two location.

I have coordinates(latitude,longitude) for both location.

How can i achieve this functionality?

Thanks,

Jim.

Comment: Check out this question on SO: "How do i open Google Maps for directions using coordinates on the iphone" which explains how to use the Maps URL scheme to plot a direction between two points.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548024/

Comment: There is also this question on drawing routes on the map: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085749/google-map-route-draw-on-iphone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use google maps API to obtain path elements of the route and then draw them over the map. Also there's a MapKit extension by Kishikawa Katsumi available for download on [github](http://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/MapKit-Route-Directions) that provides this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Vladimir is right.See another sample code here

[Drawing routes on mapkit](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=3&ved=0CBEQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fspitzkoff.com%2Fcraig%2F%3Fp%3D65&rct=j&q=drawing+routes+on+mapkit&ei=ASdMS822EIrW7AOowKmADA&usg=AFQjCNHajj2i6qRPZAWU3QitTPFT04WZQw&sig2=rNrYoU_cejCiqAuY0bL3xQ)

Answer (score 0):

`- (CGPoint)convertCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate toPointToView:(UIView *)view`, `CGContextMoveToPoint` and `CGContextAddLineToPoint` should get you started.