# Show a particular place in google maps app after clicking a link

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I would like to click a button in my iOS (11.3) app, which would open google maps at a particular location.

I have both **id** an **place_id** for my place but I don't know how to use them.

Here is the link that I constructed but it fails to open

```
world.location = "comgooglemaps://?q=place_id:\(place.1["place_id"].stringValue)&center=" + latlong;
```

GoogleMaps launches but it responds with "No results" for my place_id. Also, the **place_id:** is visible in the search bar in the app.

And this is how I attempt to open the link

```
@IBAction func search(_ sender: UIButton) {
   UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string : world.location)!)
}
```

Comment: How do you generate the location URL?

Comment: @Alper, sorry I thought it was clear from the question. I added the property name to the first code snippet.

Comment: Then please the result of that generation.

Comment: I don't see `id` and `place_id` in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/ios-urlscheme Where did you find yours?

Comment: @Larme, I couldn't find it in the docs page either but i thought it might be available since it is possible to click on businesses in the app and see details about them. Also I was steered to try the above code by reading the following answer (which has a comment for ios 11) - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46209135

Answer (score 0):

Hi Ando go through the following link. I guess you will know the answer there, your URL is not right.
URL - [How do i open Google Maps for directions using coordinates on the iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548024/how-do-i-open-google-maps-for-directions-using-coordinates-on-the-iphone)